# Auto-refresh content inside a div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know this question has been asked several times. And I have read all the threads without coming to a solution. I use Wordpress, together with a plugin, this plugin lets me add events to it. I use the "shortcode"/[slug] on a Wordpress page. This displays the events I have added. If I add or remove an event I need to manually refresh the page to see this.

My goal is to be able to see the new events (and removed) without refreshing the whole page.
If I check the page with chrome together with the source I find that a div id="vs" is what contains all the events.
I have made an addition to the plugin where I've created a javascript.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com",
    success: function( data ) {
        $("#vs").html( $(data).find('div').html());
    }
})
}, 5000); // refreshing after every 5000 milliseconds
})
```

What happens is that it is refreshed automatically. But it displays a lot of elements, and it is a duplicate of the content that was already there. And everything is offset too.

I really don't know what to try?
And also, the page which this is displayed on is a slider, both displaying the same slug, but it only "works" on the first slider.

Any ideas?

Comment: `data` contains `HTML Elements`?

Comment: "But it displays a lot of elements" Well I guess it will display what you told it to (i.e. all the `div`s within `data`) - is that a lot? Also is what's downloaded intended to entirely replace the "vs" element, or merely fit within it? Because the .html() method doesn't replace the whole element, only its contents.

Comment: What is returned in `data`?

Comment: We really need to see a `console.log( data );` example added to your question, and also a snippet of the *real* html that you have for the `#vs` element (and some of its surrounding elements) which you can copy/paste from view source.

Answer (score 0):

So it's a little hard to answer without seeing what all the dom looks like but it sounds like you are not replacing the content but rather just adding to it over and over again.  As a result, slowly the width content is getting smaller and smaller which is why you get the indenting affect. My guess is you're using .html when you want to be using .replaceWith
http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com",
    success: function( data ) {
        $("#vs").replaceWith( $(data).find('div').html());
    }
})
}, 5000); // refreshing after every 5000 milliseconds
```

If this doesn't work I think we need to see what your dom looks like.

Comment: That is more like it, but I still don't get the right result. I have changed the javascript to this: $( '#vs' ).replaceWith( $( "<h2>New heading</h2>" ) );
Which is replacing the #vs with "New Heading". But how do I replace #vs with #vs? Because I only want to refresh the div which is called #vs.

Tried $( '#vs' ).replaceWith( $( "#vs" ) ); but it is only empty.